# Similiar reconstruction for Pytorch VAE

Tags: pytorch, vae, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

*This is my first question here, so if I don't offer enough information for my question to be answered, please let me know.*

I am currently working on my Bachelor Thesis, in which I aim to integrate different neural data modalities of the [ABIDE Dataset](http://preprocessed-connectomes-project.org/abide/index.html) in a shared latent space using crossmodal VAEs based on [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-20249-2).

One of those modalities is functional connectivity. Basically, I computed the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficients of fMRT activation for individuals, resulting in a 392x392 correlation matrix, of which I then extract the lower triangle, resulting in a flat 76.636 point array, used as one of my input modalities, subject to reconstruction by the VAE.

The model is a fairly simple fully connected VAE, which yields great results for reconstruction for other modalities (namely cortical thickness and brain area).

```
class FC_VAE(nn.Module):
    """Fully connected variational Autoencoder"""
    def __init__(self, n_input, nz, n_hidden=1024):
        super(FC_VAE, self).__init__()
        self.nz = nz
        self.n_input = n_input
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_input, n_hidden),
                                nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                )

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, nz)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, nz)

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(nz, n_hidden),
                                     nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                     nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                     nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                     nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                     nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                     nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                     nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                     nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                     nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
                                     nn.BatchNorm1d(n_hidden),
                                     nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
                                     nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_input),
                                    )
    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
        z = self.reparametrize(mu, logvar)
        res = self.decode(z)
        return res, z, mu, logvar

    def encode(self, x):
        h = self.encoder(x)
        return self.fc1(h), self.fc2(h)

    def reparametrize(self, mu, logvar):
        std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            eps = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
        else:
            eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
        eps = Variable(eps)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)

    def decode(self, z):
        return self.decoder(z)

model_func = FC_VAE(n_input=76636,nz=128).to(device)

# setup optimizer
opt_netfunc   = torch.optim.Adam(params=list(model_func.parameters()), lr=1e-4)

# loss criteria
criterion_reconstruct = nn.MSELoss()
criterion_classify    = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Training loop is straightforward as well:

```
def compute_KL_loss(mu, logvar):
    if args.lamb>0:
        KLloss = -0.5*torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
        return args.lamb * KLloss
    return 0

def train_autoencoders(func_inputs):
    model_func.train()

  model_func.zero_grad()
    func_recon, func_latents,func_mu, func_logvar = model_func(func_inputs)
    func_recon_loss = criterion_reconstruct(func_inputs, func_recon)
    kl_loss = args.beta*(compute_KL_loss(func_mu,func_logvar))
    loss =  func_recon_loss+ kl_loss
    # backpropagate and update model
    loss.backward()
    opt_netfunc.step()
    summary_stats = {'func_recon_loss': func_recon_loss,'KL_loss':kl_loss.item()}
    return summary_stats
```

I then just iterate for X epochs over my dataloader.

However, my reconstruction loss doesn't seem to overfit, but rather approximate some number significantly higher than zero, regardless of latent dimensions or model size (here: 128 latent dimensions as a bottleneck)

[image]

If I then look at the reconstructions (transformed back to correlation matrices), they all look pretty much the same, but not alike the original.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how I could improve the reconstruction? I've played around with the weighing of the KL Term, but it does not seem to have any impact.

Thank you so much for your time!

Felix

Comment: Try to overfit it on one particular correlation matrix, if it does not manage to overfit then your network is just too small or not expressive enough. You will need to add some layers or try CNN architecture.